# Adaptive Server Enterprise ASCII function for multi-byte characters

Tags: oracle, ascii, special-characters, sap-ase, multibyte

While converting from Oracle to Sybase ASE I encounter the following issue: ASCII function doesn't return code for multi-byte characters properly, it looks like it gets only the first byte. 
For example, the following statement returns 34655

> select ASCII('㍉') from dual

while in Sybase it returns 63

> select ASCII('㍉')

Adaptive Server has the following language settings
Language: Japanese
Character Set: eucjis

Even if I use Sybase uscalar function

> select uscalar('㍉')

it returns 63
Only passing to uscalar function hex equivalent of this Japanese symbol gives different result, but not the same as in Oracle

> select uscalar(0x875F)

returns 24455

But in this way another issue appears - I'm not able to cast this symbol to hex as

> select convert(varbinary,'㍉')

returns only the first byte again (0x3f)

Please help me to find out the appropriate way of getting the correct ASCII code of multi-byte Japanese symbols in Adaptive Server Enterprise.